# Physics body with custom shape

Tags: andengine

I want to make a **physics body** like [this image](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bxo7e258fQibZjVQY011Y2YxRlE/edit?usp=sharing).

The **red** color ellipse will be the physics body and the curved antenna shapes will not included in the physics body.

I want to know how to call the function to create it. Like:

```
body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, this, BodyType.DynamicBody, objectFixtureDef);
```

Comment: Why exactly are you calling "createBoxBody" and trying to make an ellipse?

Comment: Also, take a look at this: http://www.andengine.org/forums/physics-box2d-extension/box2d-question-shapes-t9040.html

Comment: Not exactly "createBoxBody", I mean if there something like it. For  example there is "createCircleBody" method.

Comment: Please read the documentation for your "PhysicsFactory".  Voting to close as too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Physics Editor for this purpose. If you don't know anything about it then get proper information about it.

Following link gives you direct link to download [Physics Editor](http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor/download)

Physics Editor generate xml file and many other format that you want. You have to add sprite and create vertex that you want available in the body. Then generate a file that contain information about the body that you want to create. So that you have to only parse that information and provide as argument to polygon shape.

Comment: Is there no way to create something like it with "PhysicsFactory"?

Comment: You can use PhysicsFactory.createPolygonBody() method for this purpose and provide list data that you read from the file.